# Cloudflare and block list (block all IP by default ?)

Tags: ip, subnet, ddos, cloudflare

My server is under DDoS attack.

I would like to know if it is possible to block all possible IP from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255  or all countries. And alow only some IP/countries ?

My website need traffics from 4 countries, the rest can be banned but I don't want to ban each countries 1 by 1.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://drupal.org/node/1506532#comment-5878822) Read this entire page, but this comment in particular might help you

Comment: I'm not sure about what I have to read ? How it can help me ? I have the business offer for all my domains

Comment: First read the question (which is similar to your one), and then read the answer

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be something CloudFlare could help setup for you, since it would actually be commands you would do server side (we don't touch or manage your server). Your hosting provider should be able to help. We don't have that option available in CloudFlare's Threat Control at this time.

Note: This might help with [blocking countries on your server](http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker).

You also want to make sure that [CloudFlare's IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips) aren't being blocked. Some of our IP space appears to be from countries other than the USA.